# what is the difference between multi-linear coefficient and multiple linear regression

Tags: calculus, probability, matrices, statistics

what is multilinear coefficient? I heard it a couple of times and I tried to google it, all I am getting is multiple linear regression. 
I am confused at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean Multivariate Linear Regression by multi-linear coefficient:

In Multiple Linear Regression you have multiple predictors /independent variables ($x_1,\cdots,x_n$) and only one depentend variable $y$:
$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\cdots+\beta_nx_n$$

In Multivariate Linear Regression you have multiple predictors ($x_1,\cdots,x_n$) and multiple dependent variabes $y_i$:
$$y_1=\beta_{01}+\beta_{11}x_1+\cdots+\beta_{n1}x_n$$
$$\cdots$$
$$y_m=\beta_{0m}+\beta_{1m}x_1+\cdots+\beta_{nm}x_n$$

Answer (score 0):

A multilinear map is a function which is linear in all arguments, i.e. of the form (for three vector variables in two dimensions)

$$m(\mathbf p,\mathbf q,\mathbf r)=\\Ap_xq_xr_x+Bp_yq_xr_x+Cp_xq_yr_x+Dp_yq_yr_x+Ep_xq_xr_y+Fp_yq_xr_y+Gp_xq_yr_y+Hp_yq_yr_y.$$

It is possible to perform linear regression on such a model, but this is uncommon.